# export multiple (nested) layers of inkscape svg via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, inkscape

I want to export multiple layrs from an inkscape svg.

The structure is like this:
like:

- background

  - layerA

    - layer1
    - layer2
  - layerB

    - layer3
    - layer4

And there are more (sub) groups, because I imported other svg objects that already had svg:g nodes.

I want to export one png with Background and LayerA (including sublayers) and one png with Background and Layer3 (including sublayers) .

I tried the way described here: http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.de/2013/03/export-layers-from-svg-files-to-png.html (second example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    >
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="svg:g"/>
    <xsl:template match="svg:g[@inkscape:label='background']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerA']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layer3']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I only get the objects directly under the selected layers.
Everything that is inside another svg:g is not copied.
I want **everything** under a selected layer to be copied.

How can I do that?

Thank for your help

------EDIT-----

I think I came a little closer to my goal.

Instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="svg:g[@inkscape:label='background']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerA']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layer3']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I use this:

```
<xsl:template match="svg:g[@inkscape:label='background']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerA']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layer3']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now the subcildren are copied as wished.
But the group element itself is missing.

------EDIT2------
Now using:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

Only it does not match for groups in the sub-children level.

I think I need something like this (notice "//"):

```
<xsl:template match="//svg:g[@inkscape:label='layer3']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it does not match on layer3. :(